# Namespace name 'Notify' does not exist in the namespace Twilio.Rest

Tags: c#, namespaces, twilio, twilio-api

I followed the Documentation and had successfully implemented Twilio and had also tested it by sending myself a SMS.

As I progressed onward to "Create Bindings", I start to get errors.

> The type or namespace name 'Notify' does not exist in the namespace 'Twilio.Rest' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> The name 'BindingResource' does not exist in the current context

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

It seems like context "BindingResource' and the 'Notify' Namespace is only applicable in Twilio's **alpha version** 5.5.2.

Comment: This is correct, we are maintaining alpha libraries that contain code for any of our APIs that are in beta as the API or implementation in the library may change with feedback. Once the API reaches general availability, it will appear in the main library.